# Use an app like pm2 from another user in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

There is a question I have which is I have a `pm2` setup from my user in Ubuntu and I want to create another user and want to give him the access to `pm2` from my user for example he want's to see the logs using the `pm2 logs`. What should I do to achieve this goal?

Comment: What is a "`pm2` setup"? Where are the files installed? What happens when the other user tries?

Comment: `pm2` is a cluster for running node apps. It's installed by node in my user.